# I have a problem when working with react-router-dom version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite, swc

Here is the problem, first this project is generated using vite. I have the error that says `Warning: React does not recognize the` activeStyle `prop on a DOM element`. That is a first few lines from the error. I issue comes up when I add the activeStyle prop in the NavLink component from `react-router-dom` which should be its built-in prop however react does not recognize that as a valid prop, how could that be ? Do you have any idea whats happening ?

here is the component in the project that contains the eror:

**Header.jsx**

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <NavLink to="/" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" }}>
        Home
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" }}>
        About
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import sass from "sass";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: sass,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**here is the snapshot of the error in the console:**
[image]

Comment: `activeStyle` is not documented: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link Are you sure it's a prop? You can always check the source code if you don't trust the docs.

Comment: yeah its not the navlink valid prop, I get that from online reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no activeStyle prop but there's the regular style prop that doesn't behave as it would do in a regular component where you would pass the styles object to it

it works slightly different with the navlink component as it works as a render prop
where you would pass a callback function and the navlink component will take care of the styling
you can read more about it from here
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

here's an example

```
  const styles = {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textDecoration: "underline",
    color: "#161616",
  };



<nav className="header-nav">
        <NavLink
          style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? styles : null)}
          to="/Host"
        >
          Host
        </NavLink>
```

also by default, an active class is added to a  component when it is active so you can use CSS to style it.

```
.header-nav a.active {
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #161616; }
```